# Joining two sentences using "which"?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, relative-pronouns

I have following constructions,

> 1. The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models is then performed using graph cut approach.
> 2. The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma.

If I make a one sentence using *which*; then am I placing ***which*** at the correct place obeying the correct English grammar (see in my below sentence please)?

> The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models is then performed
>   using a graph cut approach *which* can be considered as a corner fixing
>   dilemma.

Comment: Hi gnp, this seems to be a proofreading question, which we don't generally tend to support here on ELL.  Can you add more information to your question, such as what parts of the sentence you think might not be correct and why?

Comment: @WendiKidd: sorry, i will update the post

Comment: gnp, how about "The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models, which can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma, is then performed using graph cut approach"?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: that mean, the description on first thing always come after that? like The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models, which can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma, is......

Comment: gnp, sorry I'm a learner who is learning English *via* osmotic process, not *via* English grammar. However I suppose that both a RC and a NRC should follow the NC. I hope compentent grammarians answer to your question giving all the details.

Comment: @gnp Thanks, much better! :)  As a side note, you should probably hyphenate "corner-fixing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models is then performed using a graph cut approach **which** can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma.

In that sentence, *which* is referring to "a graph cut approach."

If you want to use *which* referring it to "the geometric reconstruction" you should use a sentence similar to the following one:

> The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models, **which** can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma, is then performed using a graph cut approach.

I would rather use the following sentence, but that is probably a matter of style.

> The geometric reconstruction of the pentagon models is then performed using a graph cut approach, and it can be considered as a corner fixing dilemma.

Comment: this mean, "it" refers to the geometric reconstruction or..?

Comment: It refers to "the geometric reconstruction."